# Cómo modificar los bordes de un menú

Tags: css3

Me solicitaron crear una página web muy sencilla, plana. Es sólo para presentar una vez. Me pidieron que si el menú podría tener un estilo que no sé cómo realizarlo: Quieren que los bordes izquierdo y derecho parezca una flecha.

Así me lo están solicitando:

[image: Muestra de cómo deseamos el menú.]

Como pueden ver, tiene "flechas" en los costados.

Así estoy trabajando el menú en este momento:

```css
* {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: "Futura Condensed BQ";
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#manual {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  max-width: 60px;
}

.franja_verde {
  background-color: #ADEF1D;
}

.franja_negra {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#primera_franja {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#segunda_franja {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
}

#pie {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #ADEF1D;
  text-align: center;
}

.caja_aventura {
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-family: "BlowBrush";
  transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(30deg);
  background-color: #000000;
}

.bloque_pregunta {
  padding: .5;
  background-color: #ADEF1D;
  max-width: 480px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Chalkboard SE";
  transform: rotateX(-16deg) rotateY(16deg);
}

.bloque_respuesta p {
  padding: .5;
  max-width: 480px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Futura-Bold";
}

.menu_informacion {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  min-width: 60%;
  max-width: 60%;
  min-height: 150px;
  left: 21%;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.hojas {
  max-width: 30%;
}

.enlaces {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "BlowBrush";
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ADEF1D;
}

.enlaces:hover {
  color: #ADEF1D;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.enlaces.activo {
  color: #ADEF1D;
}

.logo_menu {
  max-width: 15%;
}

.contenedor_enlaces {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8%;
  bottom: 5%;
}

*::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.iconos_varios {
  max-width: 5%;
}

.numero_contacto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.correo_contacto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
}

.redes_sociales {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 300;
}

.imagenes {
  max-height: 530px;
}

.video_principal {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  min-width: 60%;
}

.titulo_actividad {
  padding: .5;
  background-color: #ADEF1D;
  max-width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Chalkboard SE";
  transform: rotateX(-16deg) rotateY(16deg);
}

.titulo_actividad,
.imagen_actividad {
  margin: auto;
}

.imagenes_actividades {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nombre_actividad {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 25pt;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  max-width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ADEF1D;
  font-family: "BlowBrush";
  transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(30deg);
}

.texto_actividad {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#informacion_nosotros {
  font-size: 20pt;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #7E7E7E;
}

.titular {
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-family: "BlowBrush";
}

.info_contac {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 50px;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<!--Incio franjas.-->
<header>

  <!--Primera franja.-->
  <div class="franja_verde" id="primera_franja"></div>
  <!--Fin primera franja.-->
  <!--Primera franja.-->
  <div class="franja_negra" id="segunda_franja">

    <!--Llamada ícono de PDF.-->
    <a href="./manual/manual_usuario.pdf" download="Manual de usuario.pdf"><img src="../imagenes/Ayuda_Manual_PDF.png" alt="Descargar manual." id="manual" class="iconos_varios"></a>
    <!--Fin ícono PDF.-->

  </div>
  <!--Fin primera franja.-->

  <!--Inicio navegación.-->
  <nav class="menu_informacion">

    <img src="../imagenes/logo.png" alt="" class="logo_menu">

    <!--Inicio sección de celular.-->
    <div class="numero_contacto">

      <img src="../imagenes/CONTACTOS.png" alt="Contacto." class="iconos_varios">&nbsp;300 000 000

    </div>
    <!--Fin sección de celular.-->

    <!--Inicio sección de correo.-->
    <div class="correo_contacto">

      <img src="../imagenes/CORREO.png" alt="Contacto." class="iconos_varios">&nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@ecotour.com">info@ecotour.com</a>

    </div>
    <!--Fin sección de correo.-->

    <!--Inicio redes.-->
    <div class="redes_sociales">

      <img src="../imagenes/FACEBOOK.png" class="iconos_varios">
      <img src="../imagenes/INSTAGRAM.png" class="iconos_varios">
      <img src="../imagenes/YOUTUBE.png" class="iconos_varios">

    </div>
    <!--Fin redes.-->

    <!--Enlaces de la página.-->
    <div class="contenedor_enlaces">

      <a href="../" class="enlaces">INICIO</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="../actividades/" class="enlaces">ACTIVIDADES</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="" class="enlaces activo">NOSOTROS</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="../contacto/" class="enlaces">CONTACTO</a>

    </div>
    <!--Fin enlaces.-->

  </nav>
  <!--Fin navegación.-->

</header>
<!--Final franjas.-->
```

Estoy trabajándolo como si fuera un simple rectángulo. No sé muy bien cómo generar ese estilo. Tengo idea de que es posible con `:before` y/o `:after`, pero no manejo a la perfección CSS3. Por favor, agradecería muchísimo si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés varias posibilidades para resolver ese estilo.

1. Con una imagen .jpg / .png
2. Con una imagen vectorial SVG (recomiendo)

   Con una imagen podes tomarla como un elemento mas del menú y acomodarlo con css
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Crear una imagen de fondo con svg aqui te dejo un link donde vas a encontrar las practicas oficiales si? 
   https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]